# Why does the innerHTML setter not work correctly with <br> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Why is the new line rendered correctly for real DOM Elements while getting them through innerText, but not considered when I create them using some javascript?

What is wrong with this code snipet?

```js
const real = document.querySelector('p');
const fake = document.createElement('p');
fake.innerHTML = 'foo<br>bar';

console.log(real.innerText); // this is not similar
console.log(real.textContent);
console.log(real.innerHTML);

console.log(fake.innerText); // to this, but why?
console.log(fake.textContent);
console.log(fake.innerHTML);
```

```html
<p>foo<br>bar</p>
```

Comment: Because the HTML is invalid. Use `fake.innerHTML = 'foo<br />bar';` and the output is the same as the HTML is valid.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `<br>` **is** valid HTML5. (As much as I'm still a fan of XHTML, I know its time has long past...)

Comment: @Dai good point. I should have phrased it as 'not recognised as valid HTML by the browser's DOM renderer'

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan technically `<br />` is invalid HTML, but browsers chose to simply ignore the `/>`. So for example `<div />` is not a self-closing DIV but an opening tag without a matching closing tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `innerHTML` setter works correctly, the issue is in the `innerText` method which needs layout information to compute the result. Since the `fake` node is not in the DOM there is no such information so it it just ignores the `<br>`. Once the node is inserted into DOM the results are identical:

```js
const real = document.querySelector('p');
const fake = document.createElement('p');
fake.innerHTML = 'foo<br>bar';

document.body.appendChild(fake);

console.log(real.innerText); // this is not similar

console.log(fake.innerText); // to this, but why?
```

```html
<p>foo<br>bar</p>
```

Comment: Makes sense, I didn't think about it further, because I am using all this for some DOM parsing behind the scenes, where I don't really need the element. I will consider if it makes sense to insert the elements in a hidden state. Thanks for the fast response!

Answer (score -3):

That's because your are using incomplete br tag. You should use `<br />` instead of `<br >`